# ArrayIterator::valid not works

Tags: php, arrays, collections, iterator, propel

I have a Propel collection, and try iterate it. I use, the Propel collection getIterator() method to get an instance of ArrayIterator.
So, in my code:

```
$medicos = $query->find();
$it = $medicos->getIterator();
while($it->valid()){
     [...]
}
```

But my code fails, in the loop condition:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function valid() on a non-object ...

Now, when i executes:

```
$it = $medicos->getIterator();
die($it);
```

Print 1, ergo, "true". Whats happening ?. Any idea ?.
Thanks !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I catch the error. Human error xD.
In the while, i call the next element so:

```
$it = $it->next()
```

And i had to use:

```
$it->next()
```

The loop brokes at the second pass.